# How to bound content to segment in Semantic UI React?

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI with React. I want to display an external api response object within a `<code><pre>{ obj: value }</pre></code>` component. Although the response is populating, it is not bounded by or wrapping within the `<code>` tag (see image below). What is the correct way with Semantic UI to keep the content within `<code>`?

**Component**

```
<div className="four wide column" />
  <div className="eight wide column">
    <div className="ui segment">
      <code>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.props.response, null, 2)}</pre>
      </code>
    </div>
  </div>
<div className="four wide column" />
```

Result
[image]

Comment: `.ui.segment { overlow: auto }` will add scrollbars to the segment.

Comment: Thank you, this successfully resolved the issue. Small spelling correction :D "overflow" not "overlow."